# Wrote a simple clicker program, when I run it the number flashes repeatedly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I just wrote a simple clicker counter in python using the turtle module. When I run it the number just flashes over and over again, otherwise it works fine.

I've used .tracer() and .update() in any way I could think of as well as tried .mainloop(). I believe the problem is in my usage of .clear() however I have no idea how to fix this.

```
import turtle

num = 0

def counting(x, y):
    global num
    num += 1


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Clicker")
wn.screensize(600, 600)
wn.setup(650, 650, starty=15)
wn.tracer(10)

count = turtle.Turtle()
count.hideturtle()
count.color("white")
count.speed(0)

wn.onscreenclick(counting)

while True:
    wn.update()
    count.write(num, False, align="center", font=("Arial", 100, "bold"))
    count.clear()
```

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

For similar projects, I added a conditional to the loop to only update if the value changes.

```
 while True:
      old_num = num
      wn.update()
      if (old_num != num):
         count.write(num, False, align="center", font=("Arial", 100, "bold"))
         count.clear()
```

Comment: But an event-based environment like turtle shouldn't have a `while True:`.  And the OP already knows when `num` changes, it's in `counting()` which is where the `write()` belongs.

Comment: You are right. That is a better specific solution. Checking for changes is more generally useful, but we have better tools in this instance.

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler to do than you're making it.  Rather than `clear()`, I recommend `undo()` for this sort of text update application (e.g. the score in a game, a timer, etc.)  Move a dedicated turtle to where the text goes, write an initial (zero) value, and when you want a new value, do a combination of `undo()` and `write()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ('Arial', 100, 'bold')

num = 0

def counting(x, y):
    global num

    num += 1
    count.undo()  # undo previous write()
    count.write(num, align="center", font=FONT)

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.title("Clicker")
wn.setup(650, 650, starty=15)

count = Turtle(visible=False)
count.color("white")
count.write(num, align="center", font=FONT)

wn.onscreenclick(counting)
wn.mainloop()
```

(The turtle *undo* feature was added in Python 3.)  An event-based environment like turtle should never have a `while True:` in control -- it potentially blocks events you want.  You should set up all your event handlers and turn control over to the main event loop via `mainloop()` or one of its variants.  Also, avoid `tracer()` unless you fully understand what it does and you've already got *working* code that needs optimizing.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this solution worked great for me! I also realized that I was placing the .undo() after the .write() which I guess partially caused the issue. Thanks again!